# SQL Query to retrive translated value in output

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a position table

`pos_table` with column

```
position_code job_code   location_code    pos_name              BUSINESS_UNIT

1             staff      delhi           supervisor               XYZ
2            supervor   manila          technical associate      ABC

mapping table 


table_code    source_code   business_unit   target_code 

LOC            DELHI          XYZ             10
loc            MANILA         ABC             20

job            staff         XYZ             01
job            supervisor    ABC             02
```

I want a query which joins mapping table and pos_table such that

for job_code staff  in the output 01 from mapping table target_code should come
using business_unit and source_code as join.

output:

```
position_code job_code   location_code    pos_name              BUSINESS_UNIT

1               01           10            supervisor               XYZ
2               02           20            technical associate      ABC
```

for this i wrote the query :

```
select POSITION_CODE,
 coalesce(JOB_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE,JOB_CODE) JOB_CODE,
   coalesce(LOC_MAP.FUSION_HARMONIZED_CODE,LOCATION_CODE)LOCATION_CODE 
from pos_tab POS_STAG,
  MAPPING_TAB LOC_MAP,
  mapping_tab job_MAP
where 1=1
and JOB_MAP.source_code||business_unit_name = POS_STAG.JOB_CODE||business_unit_name
and LOC_MAP.TABLE_CODE ='LOC'
and job_map.table_code='JOB'
and LOC_MAP.source_code ||business_unit_name = POS_STAG.LOCATION_CODE||business_unit_name;
```

but this is not working and it is rerieving more number of rows

Comment: You've shown data that appears quite inconsistent; mixed case in the mapping table's table_code, pos table job code has 'supervor' not 'supervisor'. Is this your actual data or have you made it up for this question?

Comment: @AlexPoole- This is a sample data .. pls forgive the typos

Comment: With cleaned up values your query gets two rows, so it really isn't clear what the issue is. Please put in some realistic data that actually demonstrates the problem, and show what result you get now as well as what you want to get for that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "SOURCE_CORE_HR_CODE" is since you don't explain it in your question but I'm guessing the below is correct.

---

The problem is you are using your mapping table for two different joins so you have to join it twice.

I'm using the "new" joining syntax which has existed as a standard for over 20 years.  I suggest you using this syntax.  It is **much** easier to understand how SQL works using this syntax.  I've no idea why anyone would use the old style.

```
SELECT P.POSITION_CODE, M1.TARGET_CODE AS JOB_CODE, M2.TARGET_CODE AS LOCATION_CODE, P.JOB_CODE AS POS_NAME, P.BUSINESS_UNIT
FROM POS_TABLE P
JOIN MAPPING_TABLE M1 ON P.JOB_CODE = M1.SOURCE_CODE AND upper(M1.TABLE_CODE) = 'JOB'
JOIN MAPPING_TABLE M2 ON P.BUSINESS_UNIT = M2.BUSINESS_UNIT AND upper(M2.TABLE_CODE) = 'LOC'
```

Comment: i tried using this @Hogan but now it is retrving less number of rows ... I am trying to figure out why. will update u